# How can you join 2 databases together in MSSQL and compare rows, including nulls?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I am trying to compare two databases (that are the same, one is a backup) and I want to include any missing rows that could read as null in one of the databases.

I have a two database (`SUS_Database_1` and `SUS_Database_2`) which both have a `transaction` table and columns called `transacation_id` and `datetime`. I would like to compare the two transactions tables including all NULLS between the 2 databases.

This is as far as I got

```
SELECT db1.transaction_id, db1.datetime  
FROM SUS_Database_1.dbo.transaction db1 WITH (nolock) 
  JOIN SUS_Database_2.dbo.transaction db ON db2.transaction_id = 
db1.transaction_id
SELECT db2.transaction_id, db2.datetime  
FROM SUS_Database_2.dbo.transaction db2 WITH (nolock) 
UNION ALL
SELECT db2.transaction_id, db2.datetime  
FROM SUS_Database_2.dbo.transaction db2 WITH (nolock)
 JOIN SUS_Database_1.dbo.transaction db ON db1.transaction_id = 
db2.transaction_id
SELECT db1.transaction_id, db1.datetime   
FROM SUS_Database_1.dbo.transaction db1 WITH (nolock)
```

This will return values in 2 separate outputs, rather than with them all merged together

Comment: What kind of output do you want? Could you, please, provide few sample rows and an expected result?

Comment: If you want to merge the query then you can use UNION ALL as shown belo...Youcan take a look on EXCEPT and INTERSECT operator too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what is meant by "compare tables", but usually it's three conditions you want:

1. For same `transaction_id` rows with different values in `datetime` (including nulls)
2. Rows that exist only in DB1
3. Rows that exist only in DB2

You can get all three with one query with a simple FULL JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    db1.transaction_id AS db1_transaction_id 
  , db1.datetime AS db1_datetime
  , db2.transaction_id AS db2_transaction_id
  , db2.datetime AS db2_datetime 
FROM SUS_Database_1.dbo.transaction db1
FULL JOIN SUS_Database_2.dbo.transaction db2 ON db2.transaction_id = db1.transaction_id
WHERE db1.datetime IS NULL 
   OR db2.datetime IS NULL 
   OR db1.datetime <> db2.datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

check this one

```
SELECT db1.transaction_id, db1.datetime  
FROM SUS_Database_1.dbo.transaction db1 WITH (nolock) 
  JOIN SUS_Database_2.dbo.transaction db ON db2.transaction_id = 
db1.transaction_id
UNION ALL
SELECT db2.transaction_id, db2.datetime  
FROM SUS_Database_2.dbo.transaction db2 WITH (nolock) 
UNION ALL
SELECT db2.transaction_id, db2.datetime  
FROM SUS_Database_2.dbo.transaction db2 WITH (nolock)
 JOIN SUS_Database_1.dbo.transaction db ON db1.transaction_id = 
db2.transaction_id
SELECT db1.transaction_id, db1.datetime   
FROM SUS_Database_1.dbo.transaction db1 WITH (nolock)
```